# How to work with the files from a docker container

Tags: docker, file

I need to work with all the files from a docker container,  my approach is  to copy all the list of files from the container to my host.

I'm using the next docker commands, for example with the postgres image:

```
docker create -ti --name dummy_1 postgres bash
docker cp dummy_1:/. Documents/docker/dockerOne
```

With this I have all the container folders and files in my host.

And then the idea is to transverse all the files with the java API, and work with them and finally delete the files  and folders from local, but I would like to know if is it a better approach, maybe with Java and access directly to the container files, instead of create a local copy of the container files in my host.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really need **all** files?

Comment: Yes even the OS ones

Comment: If we can stop the container before dumping, we can use [`docker export`](https://helpmanual.io/man1/docker-export/) (this does not export the volumes, however). Another solution would be to let the java application run within the container.

Comment: @Turing85 Could you please clarify a bit the second option?  thanks!

Comment: just add the java application as jar (plus a JVM, if not already present) to the container (by writing a dockerfile) and run the java application when needed. If we have to add a JVM to the container, however, this will increase the image size by at least 100 MB for the JVM plus however large the application is

Answer (score 0):

You can build a small server app inside your docker container which feeds you the information you need at an exposed port. Thats how i would have done it.

Comment: Hello, but I have to do this with any container, it could be alpine, mysql, etc, so I don't think I can implement an API in the docker container

Comment: So the image build process is not in your control?

Comment: No the image is not under my control

Comment: That is... problematic. In this case, the container could be a `scratch` container with a single go application, so no tooling is present in the container. Thus, we cannot rely on tools within the container. This leaves us with `docker export` or `docker copy`.

Comment: @Turing85 That's not problematic at all if you are building a custom docker image and need access from within the container. I'd say is the best approach.

Comment: But in this case this is a not custom docker image, so the best approach is docker export and docker copy I think

Comment: @rasilvap I got that, but you can still extend the base image with a custom image if you have a say in the build process. If it's a hobby project ill go for it, if not than the whole problem should be rethought. Coping all the files from a docker container is a counter solution

Comment: In the initial problem the user can send any container, I don't have control on these containers and the idea is to evaluate all the files, all this process its done with a Java application

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question, but you can mount a volume when you **run**, not create the container

```
docker run -v /host/path:/container/path your_container
```

Any code in the container (e.g. Java) that modifies files at `/container/path` will be reflected on the host, and not need to be copied back in/out. Similarly, any modifications on the host filesystem will be seen in the container.

> I don't think I can implement an API in the docker container

Yes you can. You bind a TCP port using `-p` flag

Comment: [OP clarified that they need all files - even the OS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70160311/how-to-work-with-the-files-from-a-docker-container#comment124024043_70160311), so a volume mount is not an option.

Comment: @Turing85 The OS files are coming from the container, so assuming the container process ran as root, any files in the container can be copied into the host mount.

Comment: Ah. So your idea would be to have, for example, a cronjob in the container that copies the whole file system (excluding the mount) to the mount?

Comment: @Turing85 IDK about "cron", but just the main method of the Java code, sure...